# Best approach to find next True value from an index in a boolean array

Tags: python, algorithm

I have a boolean list like this:

```
test_dict = [False, False, True, False, False, True]
```

I need help with an algorithm that can find the next True value from a given position. Please note that the position is also obtained by iterating a list. Hence, please consider that loop as well when calculating time complexity.

```
> Input
> test_dict = [False, False, True, False, False, True]

Position = 3
Output:
Next true value is at 5th position
```

I have tried this with using a nested for loop, however, not sure if that is 100% optimal.
Appreciate your suggestions.

Edit: Sample Code:

```
test_dict = [False, False, True, False, False, True]
dict_sample = {"1": "2", "11":"3"}
for position, val in dict_sample.items():
    #here position is the number from where we have to start 
    # searching the test_dict list
```

Comment: Can you add your code in your question(where you're getting the position)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is a lot of `next True value` queries, it is worth to make pre-treatment and save data in additional list, so any query is answered in O(1)

```
test_dict = [False, False, True, False, False, True]
lastpos = -1
truepos = [-1]*len(test_dict)
for i in reversed(range(len(test_dict))):
    if test_dict[i]:
        lastpos = i
    truepos[i] = lastpos

for i in range(len(test_dict)):
    print(i, truepos[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the inputs on this. I figured an answer that's based on Hashmaps and searching O(1). This solution, however, is not optimised in terms of space complexity.

The idea:
Create a hashmap that stores the key as index of the list from where we obtain the position. And the value as the index of the next True value in the boolean list.

Now whenever we want to search for the next true value, we just get the hashmap value using the position key.

Sample code:

```
                for indx, val in exit_point_signal_values.items():
                    if val == True:
                        if len(temp_list) > 0:    
                            for item in temp_list:
                                exit_point_hash_dict[item] = indx
                        else:
                            exit_point_hash_dict[indx] = indx
                        temp_list.clear()
                    else:
                         exit_point_hash_dict[indx] = -1
                         temp_list.append(indx)
                         
                for indx, val in entry_point_signal_values.items():
                    
                    if val == True:
                        if exit_point_hash_dict[indx] > 0:
                             #exit_point_hash_dict's value will contain 
                             #the index of where the next True value 
                             #happens
```

Worst case time complexity O(N)

Comment: I'm not a Pythonite but isn't that a "dictionary" you've created (which may be implemented with a hash map)? In any event, that would would work but an array would be simpler and faster (with `arr[i]` being the index of the first `True` after index `i`), as @MBo, has done in his/her answer.

Comment: Agreed. That solution works for the use cases where we expect position to be sequential and incremental (1,2,3,4).
This one is to fulfil the use case where position can be random.

Comment: @Han Index list approach doesn't depend on position query order and works with random position as well